# Prevent WordPress updates from overriding custom language translations?

Tags: theme-development, updates, translation, wp-config, language

my site's language is persian and persian is a right-to-left language. Wordpress has a default installation package for this lang but for some cases like very bad translation for dashboard or default rtl style for everything (that is really annoying for theming) i installed original Wordpress in English and then use a custom language file for my theme. everything is ok but as you know for doing this i should set following line in wp-config.php file for running my theme in persian:

```
define('WPLANG', 'fa-IR');
```

but with changing this line of code in wp-config Wordpress think that i use persian version of Wordpress and say your Wordpress version is not update!

> WordPress 3.9.2 is available! Please update now.

with changing the line to its default, update message disappears! if i click the update button Wordpress installs persian package, something that i really don't want to! the only solution is change the line to its default, update wordpress and change it back to "fa-IR"! is there a better approach to do this? is there a better way? what if one of users accidentally click on update button? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your installation such that your custom Farsi language files are associated with a non-standard WPLANG value.  For example, instead of the standard 'fa_IR', maybe try something non-standard like 'farsi_IR' (or even  'myCustomFarsi_IR').

This way, when new WordPress versions are released for the "official" Farsi version, you will no longer get updated.